# Is it possible to somehow migrate from Google Code to Github?

Tags: github, google-code

We have a fairly large project, and I've decided that Google Code is not quite living up to expectations. Github looks like a much more suitable platform -- but I feel like there's no escape for us. Is it a case of migrating stuff over manually? We're using svn currently, so I understand that we'll need to move to git somehow - is this going to be possible considering that I don't have admin access to our repository? Also, I know this is subjective and I don't want to start a holy war, but please also comment on your feelings about Google Code vs Github. Should we also be considering SourceForge?

Comment: Moving the code across will be the easy part.  I'm not so sure about migrating all the issues across to GitHub's issue tracker - is that possible?

Comment: Malvineous: This is my primary concern; but the benefit may outweigh the inconvenience... Perhaps we could just close all our issues as MovedToGithub or something, and immediately close new issues with this status. Initially it will be painful, but I think long term it might make things easier. That said I haven't even registered an account on Github, so that's a massive assumption!

Comment: For anyone looking to migrate issues from gcode to github, you could try https://github.com/dave0/gcode-issue-import

Comment: Also check out https://github.com/arthur-debert/google-code-issues-migrator

Comment: @joelittlejohn, that doesn't seem to work anymore.  I get "try to get http://code.google.com/feeds/issues/p/project-name/issues/full?start-index=1&can=all&max-results=1000& failed: 404 Not Found"

Answer (score 16):

I've used all, and now I am using github and I am completely satisfied. Sourceforge had annoying ads and was slow, google code didn't have the features I wanted/needed.

As for moving to github, they have a guide here, the process should be quite simple:
http://help.github.com/svn-importing/

Answer (score 5):

> We're using svn currently, so I understand that we'll need to move to git somehow - is this going to be possible considering that I don't have admin access to our repository?

Nope, you can use `git svn` to convert a repo, even if you don't have admin access. Here's a good [tutorial](http://progit.org/book/ch8-2.html#subversion) (from one of the GitHub guys, no doubt) that explains how to convert an SVN repo to Git (including how to migrate tags and branches properly, which `git-svn` doesn't do very well).

> but please also comment on your feelings about Google Code vs Github.

I've never used Google Code for personal projects. I know from a visitor's standpoint, I like the interface and tools used by GitHub a lot better.

> Should we also be considering SourceForge?

Ugh... I personally think SourceForge is probably the worst of the free source code hosting facilities nowadays.

Comment: Will `git svn` copy over all of the commits? Our revision history is quite important.

Comment: Yep. And if you use an `authors` file (as noted in the link above) you can even associate SVN usernames with Git committer names and email addresses properly.

Answer (score 2):

I think before you go through all the work to migrate to github (which is great yes) I would consider what your problem actually is. If it is just that you are using svn and that is not a distributed version control system you could just migrate your google code repository to be HG (Mercurial) based and you would get all the benefits of a distributed version control system but could otherwise stay at google code (which has great features that github does not have as well..)

Comment: Google Code now also supports Git. I migrated my Google Code project from SVN to Git very easily. It was basically a matter of changing an option in the preferences. The only caveat was related to migrating wiki pages and this was fully documented and yielded no unpleasant surprises. I would seem that Github is indeed the superior service. But my needs are simple and so is Google Code so I won't be switching in too much of a hurry.

Answer (score 1):

Google [announced today](http://google-opensource.blogspot.fr/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html) that they're closing Google Code. They added a [migration tool](https://code.google.com/export-to-github/) to export projects to GitHub, it just takes one click.

Comment: Apparently, that is now DEAD too. Must hack mystic json endpoints for happiness like old school fuzzing hacker. 
https://code.google.com/archive/schema